# Actuator in docker-compose doesn't run

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, actuator

I created a REST service in the Spring Boot.

`application.properties` file says that app should run on port 8081 (`server.port=8081`)

Image is made with Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY target/*.jar /app/app.jar
COPY startup.sh /app/startup.sh

RUN chmod +x startup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
```

Shell script actually do nothing more than running an app.

Later, I run my container with `docker-compose up` and an error appears. The docker-compose.yaml file looks like that:

```
services:
  service1:
    image: test_image
    ports:
      - "8082:8081"
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail localhost:8082/actuator/health | grep UP || exit 1"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
```

So I understand that port from a container (8081) should be mapped to 8082 and actuator should check if it's healthy. Unfortunately, when I run `curl localhost:8082/actuator/health` in the console, I got `{status:UP}`, but when I check `docker ps -a` I see an "**unhealthy**" information. Really don't know why this happens and what is the difference between asking curl directly and asking curl in the way this is specified in the `docker-compose.yaml` file.

Comment: the health check is run from within the container, not the host. Thus, we need to access the container port (`8081`), not the host port (`8082`). The command used in the health check (`curl` in the example) must be present in the container.

Comment: this might be linux syntax issue. try  to add brackets: `(curl --fail localhost:8081/actuator/health | grep UP) || exit 1`

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately not.